# Do grails' getter methods return COPIES of attributes objects, or the attributes objects themselves?

Tags: grails, groovy

For instance:

```
class Person {
  def stuff
}

class Toilet {
  public void main(String... args){
      Person person = new Person()
      person.getStuff()  //null, but you get my point
  } 
}
```

Does `getStuff()` returns a copy of `stuff`? Or the `stuff` itself?
I'm concerned about the *modifiability* of the returned `stuff` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groovy (used by Grails) returns object itself, but for objects only (`def`, `Object`, `Person`, etc). You can modify this object.

And a copy for primitives (`int`, `long`, etc).

It's the same as for Java.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the stuff itself, unless you're doing an explicit copy in the getter and returning this copy.
There is no generic way in Java (and thus Groovy) to make a copy of an object anyway.